# Swap command line and status-line?

Tags: command-line, statusline

Is it possible to swap the order of the command line and status line, such that the status line is flush with the bottom?

Or better yet, completely disable the command line - but I understand that not to be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. What you call the "mode line" is actually called "command line".
2. You can't move it around.
3. You can't disable it.

Comment: I didn't know what it was called, the tag seemed to refer to it though? Shame about the answer, but thanks nonetheless.

Comment: No "modeline" is something else entirely. See `:help modeline`.

Answer (score 1):

In [Vim 9.0.0114](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f39cfb72629f3e7fefaf578a3faa2619cd0654f8) and [Neovim 0.8 (prerelease)](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases), `set cmdheight=0` hides the command line.